# Eclipse Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

I am working on a Java program called Namesurfer for a home assignment. The program consists of five classes: 'NameSurfer, NameSurferConstants, NameSurferDataBase, NameSurferEntry, and NameSurferGraph.
The code is (I thought) complete, but when I put the name on NameSurfer console and press enter, I get the following error. And when I click Graph, it doesn't do anything.

My suspicion is it has something to do with NameSurferEntry class, but I've been looking for hours without success. I'm really new at Java, and any help will be appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at NameSurfer.actionPerformed(NameSurfer.java:58)
at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:492)
at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:705)
at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:820)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1645)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2859)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2894)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2822)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6159)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1856)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:722)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1000)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:865)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:686)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4616)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:683)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:681)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Here's the code for NameSurfer.

```
/*
 * File: NameSurfer.java
 * ---------------------
 * When it is finished, this program will implements the viewer for
 * the baby-name database described in the assignment handout.
*/

import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NameSurfer extends Program implements NameSurferConstants {

/* private instance variables*/
private JButton graphButton;
private JButton clearButton;
private JLabel nameLabel;
private JTextField name;
private NameSurferGraph graph;
private NameSurferDataBase dataBase;

/**
 * This method has the responsibility for reading in the data base
 * and initializing the interactors at the top of the window.
 */
public void init() {
    addActionListeners();
    graph = new NameSurferGraph();
    add(graph);

    /* adds the control bar*/
    nameLabel = new JLabel ("Name");
    add(nameLabel, NORTH);

    name = new JTextField(MAX_FONT_NAME);
    name.addActionListener(this);
    add(name, NORTH);

    graphButton = new JButton ("Graph");
    add(graphButton, NORTH);

    clearButton = new JButton ("Clear");
    add(clearButton, NORTH);


}

/**
* This class is responsible for detecting when the buttons are
 * clicked, so you will have to define a method to respond to
 * button actions.
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals ("Clear")) {
        graph.clear();
        graph.update();
    } else {
        String inputName = name.getText();
        NameSurferEntry entry = dataBase.findEntry(inputName);
        if (entry != null) {
            graph.addEntry(entry);
            graph.update();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here's the code for NameSurferEntry.

```
/*
 * File: NameSurferEntry.java
 * --------------------------
 * This class represents a single entry in the database.  Each
 * NameSurferEntry contains a name and a list giving the popularity
 * of that name for each decade stretching back to 1900.
 */

import acm.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class NameSurferEntry implements NameSurferConstants {

/* private instance variables*/
private String name;
private int[] ranks = new int [NDECADES];

/**
 * Creates a new NameSurferEntry from a data line as it appears
 * in the data file.  Each line begins with the name, which is
 * followed by integers giving the rank of that name for each
 * decade.
 */
public NameSurferEntry(String line) {
    //gets the name
    int nameEnd = line.indexOf(" ");
    name = line.substring(0, nameEnd);

    //gets the ranking and forms it into an array using StringTokenizer class
    String rankingStart = line.substring(nameEnd + 1);
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(rankingStart);
    for (int i = 0; tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
            int yearRank = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            ranks[i] = yearRank;
        }

}

/* Method: getName() */
/**
 * Returns the name associated with this entry.
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/* Method: getRank(decade) */
/**
 * Returns the rank associated with an entry for a particular
 * decade.  The decade value is an integer indicating how many
 * decades have passed since the first year in the database,
 * which is given by the constant START_DECADE.  If a name does
 * not appear in a decade, the rank value is 0.
 */
public int getRank(int decade) {
    if (decade <NDECADES) {
    return ranks[decade];
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Method: toString() */
/**
 * Returns a string that makes it easy to see the value of a
 * NameSurferEntry.
 */
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
        result += getRank(i);
    }
    return ("\"" + name + "[" + result + "]\"");
}
}
```

And here's the code for NameSurferGraph.

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class NameSurferGraph extends GCanvas implements NameSurferConstants, ComponentListener {

/*Private instance variables*/
private ArrayList <NameSurferEntry> dataDisplay;

/**
 * Creates a new NameSurferGraph object that displays the data.
 */
public NameSurferGraph() {
    addComponentListener(this);
    dataDisplay = new ArrayList<NameSurferEntry>();
}

/**
 * Clears the list of name surfer entries stored inside this class.
 */
public void clear() {
    dataDisplay.clear();
    update();
}

/**
 * Adds a new NameSurferEntry to the list of entries on the display.
 * Note that this method does not actually draw the graph, but
 * simply stores the entry; the graph is drawn by calling update.
 */
public void addEntry(NameSurferEntry entry) {
    dataDisplay.add(entry);
}


/**
 * Updates the display image by deleting all the graphical objects
 * from the canvas and then reassembling the display according to
 * the list of entries. Your application must call update after
 * calling either clear or addEntry; update is also called whenever
 * the size of the canvas changes.
 */
public void update() {
    removeAll();
    drawGraph();
    if (dataDisplay.size() >= 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataDisplay.size(); i++) {
            NameSurferEntry entry = dataDisplay.get(i);
            drawRankingGraph (entry, i);
        }
    }
}

/*draws the background grids and displays the years*/
private void drawGraph() {
    drawMargins();
    drawVerticalLines();
    displayYears();
}

/*Draws the horizontal lines at the top and the bottom of the window*/
private void drawMargins() {
    double x1 = 0;
    double x2 = getWidth();
    double y1 = GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE;
    double y2 = getHeight() - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE;
    GLine topLine = new GLine (x1, y1, x2, y1);
    GLine bottomLine = new GLine (x1, y2, x2, y2);
    add(topLine);
    add(bottomLine);

}

/*Draws the vertical lines*/
private void drawVerticalLines() {
    double x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NDECADES; i++) {
        GLine verticalLine = new GLine (x, 0, x, getHeight());
        x += getWidth() / NDECADES;
        add(verticalLine);
    }
}

/*Displays the years*/
private void displayYears() {
    int decade = START_DECADE;
    double x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NDECADES; i++) {
        GLabel label = new GLabel ("" + decade);
        add(label, x, getHeight() - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE/2 + (label.getAscent() / 2));
        decade += NUMBER_OF_YEARS;
        x += getWidth() / NDECADES;
    }
}

/*Draws the ranking graph and the input name label*/
private void drawRankingGraph(NameSurferEntry entry, int n) {
    int inputOrder = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < NDECADES - 1; i++) {
        int r1 = entry.getRank(i);
        int r2 = entry.getRank(i + 1);

        double x1 = i * (getWidth()/NDECADES);
        double x2 = (i+1) * (getWidth()/NDECADES);
        double y1 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;
        if (r1 == 0) {
            y1 = getHeight() - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE;
        } else {
            y1 = GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE + (getHeight() - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE*2) * r1 / MAX_RANK;
        }
        if (r2 == 0) {
            y2 = getHeight() - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE;
        } else {
            y2 = GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE + (getHeight() - GRAPH_MARGIN_SIZE*2) * r2 / MAX_RANK;
        }

        /*Sets the graph and the label on the window*/
        GLine rankingGraph = new GLine (x1, y1, x2, y2);
        GLabel inputName = new GLabel(entry.getName() + " " + (entry.getRank(i) == 0 ? "*" : entry.getRank(i)));

        /*Sets the color*/
        Color color = getColor(inputOrder%4);
        rankingGraph.setColor(color);
        inputName.setColor(color);

        /*Displays the graph and the label*/
        add(rankingGraph);
        add(inputName, x1, y2);
    }
}

/*Gets the color of the rankingGraph and the inputName label*/
private Color getColor(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0: return Color.black;
    case 1: return Color.red;
    case 2: return Color.blue;
    }
    return Color.magenta;
}


/* Implementation of the ComponentListener interface */
public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) { }
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) { }
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) { update(); }
public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) { }

}
```

Comment: tl;dr, where is exactly line 58 of class `NameSurfer`?

Answer (score 1):

Your "database" seems to be null.

Note that you either provided incomplete NameSurfer source or you need to recompile your application - line numbers are off, line 58 only has a closing brace.

Comment: I've recompiled it. Would be great if you could have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: `NameSurfer.java:58` line is `} else {` now - it does not make sense. Stack trace is still not in sync with the source code you've posted. From the code inspection, I do not see where you are setting field dataBase. Can the actual NPE originate on line 60 (`dataBase.findEntry(inputName);`)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the usage of "actionPerformed" method. You're probably trying to use it on something which is not set and therefore "null".

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method on an object that's null at NameSurfer.java:58 .  Find out what can be null on that line and figure out why it's null even though you expect it not to be.

Unrelated to that, read up on the Java Naming Conventions.  Only your type names should start with an uppercase.